# When do HTTP requests not carry cookies?

Tags: http, browser, cookies

Is there any case where the browser is sending an HTTP request to a server but does *not* attach cookies associated with that domain to the request? If so, what are the cases?

Comment: If your intent is to prevent sending cookies for HTTP-requests that request static resources (like images, JS scripts, style sheets, etc.),ergo, in cases where the cookies are useless to the server, then put those resources on a different "static" domain that does not create cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are set by the server first, or are set by a javascript that is executed in a page from that domain. So every cookie you get, it a cookie you have set earlier.

Normal cookies are sent to the server with each request, Ajax as well as regular page loads and posted data. There are some new features like offline storage that is implemented by more and more browsers, but those features are not cookies.

Answer (score 0):

A cookie can have a domain and path associated with it, thus limiting which resources the cookies are sent to.

```
document.cookie = 'name=value; expires=' + date.toGMTString() + '; path=/myFolder; domain=myDomain';
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Chrome (as of version 25) [does not include cookies in favicon requests](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=180764#c3). Also, it is apparently [standard for other browsers to not share cookies between the favicon requests and other requests](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=114082#c1).